How to fix this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" when trying to push publicKey to an array
This is my code. I don't understand what this error is for. My console shows the account data has been added to the array successfully.
for (const accountInfo of allAccounts) {
            const account = unpackAccount(
                accountInfo.pubkey,
                accountInfo.account,
                TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
            );
            const transferFeeAmount = getTransferFeeAmount(account);

            if (transferFeeAmount !== null && transferFeeAmount.withheldAmount > bigInt(0)) {
                accountsToWithdrawFrom.push(accountInfo.pubkey);
            }
        }

        
        console.log(accountsToWithdrawFrom);
        console.log(withdrawAccount)

        const ix = createWithdrawWithheldTokensFromAccountsInstruction({
            mint: new PublicKey(mint),
            destination: new PublicKey(withdrawAccount),
            authority: publicKey.value,
            signers: undefined,
            sources: accountsToWithdrawFrom, // Ensure accountsToWithdrawFrom is properly initialized
            programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        });

Screenshots of the error.


There may be other errors, but createWithdrawWithheldTokensFromAccountsInstruction takes the parameters one by one, and not as an object, so you should do:
        const ix = createWithdrawWithheldTokensFromAccountsInstruction(
            new PublicKey(mint),
            new PublicKey(withdrawAccount),
            publicKey.value,
            [],
            accountsToWithdrawFrom,
            TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
        );

Source code at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/d1c03cc6164ebdeebef19190de28b7a71f4e4cb6/token/js/src/extensions/transferFee/instructions.ts#L550 for reference
